# Animating the width of a div using percentages in jquery

Tags: jquery, width

I'm trying to change the width of a div, in percentages, when a button (in this case another div) is clicked. I have it working in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vkk907nt/2/), but cannot successfully recreate it in the actual code for my site, an example of which is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p3u4pz5j/). They are both identical to my eyes, but something is apparently going wrong.

The javascript being used is:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
if(!collapsed){
    $('.left').animate({width: '10%'});
} else {
    $('.left').animate({width: '50%'});
}
collapsed = !collapsed; });
```

Yet, at least in the second example, nothing results of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues with your version:

1. the jsFiddle did not include jQuery.
2. You did not define the `collapsed` variable, so you were getting an error in the console.

Fix those problems and it works. Also note that you can make the width change a one-liner using a ternary expression:

```
var collapsed = false;
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('.left').animate({ width: collapsed ? '50%' : '10%' });
    collapsed = !collapsed;
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/p3u4pz5j/2/)

It may also be worth adding `stop(true)` before calling `animate()` to prevent successive clicks filling up the animation queue.

Comment: Ah, novice mistake! Thank you very much, especially for the recommendation.